# Use find to count files by date

Tags: bash

I am trying to do a count of files by date. The date is a field in the file name itself e.g.

```
CTCA~AT2~FVT~8388358~ONTAFT2-1~8~P~1100~HR24-500~033189784938~20120224~220306.VER
```

This is what I did:

```
find . -name '*VER' |awk -F~ '{print $11}'|uniq -c
```

This is the output I get:

```
  1 20120222
  3 20120222
  3 20120224
  3 20120224
  3 20120225
  5 20120225
```

But I want to sum up the counts like so

```
  4 20120222
  6 20120224
  8 20120225
```

How can I do that?

/--------------------------------------/

A simple search with

```
find . -name '*VER'
```

returns

```
...
./CTCA~AT2~FVT~8388358~ONTAFT2-1~7~P~1100~HR24-200~035699170847~20120217~150754.VER
./CTCA~AT2~FVT~8388358~ONTAFT2-1~8~P~1100~HR24-500~033066015695~20120223~204125.VER
./CTCA~AT2~FVT~7561825~ONTAFT2-1~4~P~1100~HR24-100~035688466560~20120223~085805.VER
./CTCA~AT2~FVT~9078749~ONTAFT2-1~4~P~1100~HR24-200~035580595029~20120209~110625.VER
./CTCA~AT2~FVT~7561825~ONTAFT2-1~5~P~1100~HR22-100~028933090384~20120223~104932.VER
...
```

Comment: could you provide the result of find . -name '*VER' ?  Or a sensible subset?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's exactly what `uniq -c` should do. If it isn't working it's because your input isn't sorted. Try this:

```
find . -name '*VER' |awk -F~ '{print $11}'|sort|uniq -c
```

Comment: I guess I was close to figuring it out...lol. Accepted and voted up. Thank you!!!

Answer (score 2):

Here is my solution, which skips the uniq command:

```
find ... | awk -F~ '{count[$11]++} END{for (d in count) {print count[d], d}}
```

The strategy is to create an array called **count**, using the dates as indices. At the end, print them out.